# Web applications: servlet thread safety using singleton pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm looking to hopefully get into web application programming using Java, coming from a PHP/Laravel background (I have some Java experience having studied it around about 8 years ago at university).

I've been playing around for a while and feel fairly comfortable with most of the foundational concepts such as Servlets and Servlet containers as well as some popular web server/servlet container technologies used such as Jetty, Tomcat etc. I've also tried to do quite a bit of research into Java EE.

Now since I want to build up my knowledge on the subject, I don't want to use any frameworks, in fact I would like to look to build my own as a learning exercise. However, I've also looked quite a bit into some of the frameworks around, such as Spring MVC, Struts, Play and Vaadin etc.

So I've got a Maven project set up, I have a `web.xml` file set up pointing at a servlet that I have created and I am looking to build an entry point into my "framework".

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mypackage.Application</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**src/main/java/com/mypackage/Application.java**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Application extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // 
    }
}
```

So now I want to make my own IoC container that uses the singleton pattern (I know this is usually discouraged and is considered an anti-pattern), so it is easy to access it from other parts of my application:

**src/main/java/com/mypackage/Container.java**

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Container {
    private static Container instance;

    public static Container make(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return instance = new Container();
    }

    public static Container getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            // Throw an exception
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private Container(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to create a Container object for every request/response cycle (or every servlet) as the entry point to my application. So I would look to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Container container = Container.make(request, response);

    // Do stuff with container and eventually respond to the client
}
```

Now I know that thread safety is a concern when it comes to servlets, and properties on the servlet instance are shared among threads, but my question relates specifically to the Container object I'm creating using the singleton pattern and thread safety.

Is my current approach considered to be thread safe? If not, why, and how can I make it thread safe? Bear in mind that don't actually want my Container instance to be shared among each thread and would like a separate container for each incoming request/response.

Would it be thread safe (or a recommended approach) to create a new object inside the `service` method of the servlet class and then have that new object create an instance of the Container? e.g.

```
public class Something {
    public Something(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Container.make(request, response);
    }
}



@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Something something = new Something(request, response);

    // Do stuff with container and eventually respond to the client
}
```

Finally, would I be correct in assuming that the issue of thread safety arises due to the servlet container re-using servlet instances? As per the [Java EE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html):

> The life cycle of a servlet is controlled by the container in which the servlet has been deployed. When a request is mapped to a servlet, the container performs the following steps.
>
> If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the web container
>
> Loads the servlet class.
>
> Creates an instance of the servlet class.
>
> Initializes the servlet instance by calling the init method. Initialization is covered in Initializing a Servlet.

Comment: You current `Container` code does not have enough code for us to tell you if it is thread safe or not. Please google how to write singleton in Java if you need to have it singleton. If you dont need to share `Container` then why not just do `Container c = new Container()` inside your Servlet?

Comment: I've not got any more code than that so far. I know I want to use the singleton pattern though and I know how to write it. In fact I am pretty sure that the container class as it is now is not thread safe. My question isn't related to whether or not my singleton Container class is thread safe, I'm more interested in the issue of, if I initiate my singleton class inside the servlet the way I am currently doing it, then will my singleton instance be shared across other threads, or will it exist once per request/response cycle?

Comment: `Container.make(request, response)` is somewhat safe as long as you are just calling that method and ignoring `getInstance`. It is pretty much the same as `Container c = new Container()`. Cant comment on the `Container.boot` approach since I dont see what that method does.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance in the servlet means that it is not thread-safe as a servlet instance is reused.

A `Singleton` or `ApplicationScoped` object will only have one copy across your entire application. If you want to make sure that there is only one instance of the object then annotate the class with `@ApplicationScoped`:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Something {
   //do stuff
}
```

Then in the servlet inject it:

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Inject
   Something obj;

   @Override
   public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     //do stuff
   }

}
```

If instead you want the class to  you are using to be unique per request then make your class `RequestScoped` instead. Like so:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Something {
   //do stuff
}
```

For more information see the CDI tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html. Note that this will require using an application server that has CDI i.e. Payara and not just a servlet container.